# Where is the code which calls onCreate, onPause, onResume etc

Tags: android-activity, android, android-framework

From my understanding, onCreate, onPause, onResume etc are executed in the main UI thread. This is possible if some other thread (part of android framework code) attaches these calls as messages to the UI thread's queue. I want to know which thread/process and which class in framework  attaches these messages to the UI thread's queue? There should be some 'handleMessage' function that does 'myActivity.onPause'. I am not able to find it. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Mainly here.. http://gitorious.org/android-eeepc/base/trees/76eef491e1a453174f6372d18cf500d13521fb23/core/java/android/app and http://gitorious.org/android-eeepc/base/trees/76eef491e1a453174f6372d18cf500d13521fb23/core/java/android/os

Comment: I use Jellybean code on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

ActivityThread.H is the handler that pauses the activity. Under H Handler PAUSE_ACTIVITY is the message that is posted for the activity to be paused

Comment: Are you talking out this code in ActivityThread.java . case PAUSE_ACTIVITY:
1699 
                    handlePauseActivity((IBinder)msg.obj, false, msg.arg1 != 0, msg.arg2);
1700 
                    break;

Comment: But based on my logs, the 'onPause' in the App gets called, before the ActivityThread PAUSE_ACTIVITY. Which makes me think who calls, the App onPause in the first place.

Comment: I can't see how that is possible... the ActivityManagerService tells ActivityThread.java to pause the Activity and only then Activity.onPause() is called. At what point are you printing to the log?

Answer (score 0):

Check `startActivityLocked()` in `ActivityStack.java`.

Path - `framework/base/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityStack.java`